# Connected to WiFi but no Internet

Tags: networking, wireless

I finally got my WiFi to hook up to my WiFi extender, but now I have no internet. I have 100% connection, everything looks good, but when I go to Chrome or anything I have no internet connection.

I ran a ping and the info that I got back was:

```
10 packets transmitted, 7 received, 30% packet loss, time 9033ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.568/445.805/2000.159/716.866 ms pipe 2
```

I am using a 64-bit Intel Sandy Bridge desktop. I'm not sure about the wifi card. The problem that I am having is I can connect to my primary wifi, but the connection is far from good so I bought a repeater for the garage (my computer is in the garage). I used to be able to connect to the repeater, but I updated Ubuntu 16.04 a couple of days ago via the "update now or remind me later" pop-up. Ever since then I have had this issue.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: It sound more like a networking issue than a problem with Ubuntu. Does it work on other devices? Is this the first time you connected to a repeater router to the main one? If so, are you sure everything is setup correctly? I'd double check it

Comment: Yeah. I can connect any wirless device to it and they work just fine. No it's not the first time I've hooked up to the repeater. Everything is set up properly.

Comment: What is the output of `ping -c10 8.8.8.8'?

Comment: I did that yesterday and all it did was keep repeating the process. It kept giving me seconds readouts and all the number stuff. ( yes I am a Linux noob )

Comment: Any chance I could get some form of dialog going with someone? I don't have enough badges to chat with anyone about this.

Comment: Ok. The ping says 10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms

Comment: I guess something went wrong when doing the setup of the wireless network inside Ubuntu (maybe some subnetting issue, i dont know much of netowrking). You could try deleting the network and recreating it to see if anything is solved. Also, you can [edit] your current question to add more info, instead of as an answer as you did with the ping information (dont worry, some mod will convert it to a comment or edit). Maybe Ubuntu Forums could help you out better.

Comment: If you are using a DHCP router, does it assign an internal IP address, and if so, what does the router's logs say about your device? If it's not that, I could look into what commands you'd need to do a 'fresh' networking installation without jumping ship on your current system. It's definitely odd that it won't connect to a site, has 9000ms ping, yet is able to ping Google. You don't have a firewall or antivirus software installed, do you? Perhaps a VPN software, or proxy you have to login to to reach the web? One of those may have become corrupt during the update.

Comment: I know it sounds cliche, but maybe rebooting the router/modem combo could provide little insight. I also think it could have to do with the update partially. I had an issue a while back where virtualbox needed a dkms module, but the kernel headers supplying the module had to be installed manually after each update - or the networking would cease to function. -- The reason I question your router/modem combo stems from that 9000ms ping. Seems very odd...

Comment: @Dooley_labs I'm running a typical netgear hardwire/wireless router. I'm not sure wether it assigns an internal IP address  ( it probably does ). Not sure how to check the logs on the router either. I'm not running a VPN nore do I have a proxy.

Comment: @Dooley_labs Yeah I did the whole unplug and restart procedure. I'm pretty new to Linux and have no idea what virtualbox  module's are.

Comment: I wish there was a way to live chat or something with someone rather than waiting for a response. I know this is not a technical support center but man this problem is getting on my nerves.  This has been a three day problem for me.

Comment: Ok. So I think I figured out the problem. I don't know how but the settings for the IPV-4 and IVP-6 got messed with. All I did was go to a WiFi connection that half-ass worked and looked At it's settings and BAM I have a working internet. One quick question though. Is the hardware/device address supposed to be the same as the weaker WiFi one or should it have it's own? If not how do I obtain it's own?